# webrtc peer to peer video streaming between browsers using flussonic

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, p2p

I have been trying to implement a peer to peer webrtc video streaming application. 
I have followed the supplied example code from flussonic https://gist.github.com/theleon/80dd514b435e295f272988c1064d3c4c

```
`<html>
 <body>
<video id="videoElement" controls ></video>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js">
</script>
 <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var candidates = [];
        var websocket;
        var peerConnection;
        var video = document.getElementById('videoElement');
        function sendWebSocketMessage(data) {
            console.log('data:', data);
            websocket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        function onWebSocketMessage(event) {

            var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log("message:", message.type);
            switch (message.type) {
                case "offer":
                    var description = new 
        window.RTCSessionDescription(message);
        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description)
                            .then(function () {
                                var answer = peerConnection.createAnswer();
                                console.log("1 answer:",answer);

                                return answer;
                            })
                            .then(function (answer) {
                                console.log("2 answer:",answer);
                                return peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
                            })
                            .then(function () {
                                console.log("3 peerConnection.localDescription:",peerConnection.localDescription);

      websocket.send(JSON.stringify(peerConnection.localDescription));
                            });
                    break;
                case "candidate":
                    candidates.push(message);
                    if(message.candidate !== null){
                        console.log("message candidate:",message.candidate);
                        var candidate = new window.RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate);
                        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
                    }
                    console.log("candidates");
                    console.log(candidates);
                    break;
            }
        }
        function openFlussonicWebSocketConnection(options) {
            var url =
                    options.protocol + "://" +
                    options.server + ":" +
                    options.port + "/" +
                    options.stream;
            console.log("url:", url);
            websocket = new WebSocket(url);
            websocket.onopen = initPeerConnection;
            websocket.onmessage = onWebSocketMessage;
        }

        function initPeerConnection() {

            peerConnection = new window.RTCPeerConnection(null);
            peerConnection.stream_id = "remote1";
            peerConnection.onicecandidate = gotIceCandidate;
            peerConnection.ontrack = gotRemoteTrack;

            console.log("peerConnection:",peerConnection);
        }

        function gotIceCandidate(event) {
            var candidate = event.candidate;
            if (candidate) {
                sendWebSocketMessage({
                    type: 'candidate',
                    stream_id: "remote1",
                    label: candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                    id: candidate.sdpMid,
                    candidate: candidate
                });
            }
        }
        function gotRemoteTrack(event) {

            if (event.track.kind === "video") {
                video.srcObject = event.streams[0];
                //peerConnection.addStream(event.streams[0]);
            }
        }
        openFlussonicWebSocketConnection({
            "protocol": "wss",
            "server": "fluss.dev-tst.ninja",
            "port": "443",
            "stream": "indian/webrtc"
        });

      };
    </script>          
   </body>
</html>`
```

[The URL generated by flussonic is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SsM8.png)

Although the video is streamed across multiple clients on the local network, the only candidate returned by flussonic server is the server itself. I have tried adding google stun server (stun.l.google.com:19302) when I initialized the rtcpeerconnection but that also returned the server as the candidate. I feel like I am missing something with the signalling, what am I missing?

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen.  If you don't want to use a server to distribute, use WebRTC between browser peers instead.

Comment: That's what I am trying to achieve, how do I use WebRTC between browser peers?